# CSS WTF : form button not horizontally aligned (screwed up in FF but OK in Chrome)

Tags: html, css

OK here is what I found out, when I assign height to all my form elements, they will not be aligned horizontally, when **they actually should**.
Chrome rendered this OK, FF pushed the form button too far up.
Is there an elegant solution to this?

```
<form>

<input class="input_text" type="text" style="height:40px" value="some text">

<select style="height:40px">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Search" style="height:40px">


</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the button has no padding/margin:

```
style="height:40px;margin:0;padding:0"
```

Each browser does its own thing regarding padding and margin.

Find out more about [reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) and why/how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

This is vertical align, not horizontal. Looks like this is bug in FF. As the work around add the "vertical-align:top" to the button

Answer (score 0):

you can try to ditch input type button and use `<button type="submit">Hello Button</button>` then reset your form elements.

by using button tag you will have option to add nested elements. like `<button><span>Funky Button!</span></button>`  for background image tricks and so on.

reset for form elements may look something like this:

```
/*remove ie side spacing(paddings)*/
button {position:relative; border:0; padding:0; cursor:pointer; overflow:visible;}
/*remove extra padding for firefox*/
button::-moz-focus-inner {border: none;}
button span {position:relative; display:block; white-space:nowrap;}

/*fix for webkit (safari-chrome)*/
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {button span {margin-top: -1px;}}

input {border:0; margin:0; padding:0;}
textarea {border:0; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

then you can add your borders styles backgrounds as you want and they should look identical in almost every modern browser

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to be a bug in Firefox.

In the past I've fixed it with

1: a firefox specific hack.

2: not setting the height of the button ever. It remains vertically centered in all browsers.